# What does the drink that Mio ordered look like in Episode 18 of Nichijou?

Tags: nichijou

In episode 18, Yukko and Mio trying to order at a cafe which is probably *Starbucks*. Mio's order was

> I'd like grande white chocolate, mocha frappuccino, also I want a
>   short single-shot, caramel sauce, hazelnut syrup, chocolate chip, and
>   extra-whip espresso

[image: Mio's ordering the drink]

Is the order really exist, or she just said random a coffee's name in her order?

Relevant video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAzTxzEeptM).

Comment: You've never made a custom order at a starbucks have you....

Comment: You can pretty much replicate that order in most coffee shops which carry these ingredients and it'll cost you a bit more than a standard choice. Basically you can ask them to put anything together as long as they have enough of these additives in stock. Try your local coffee shops with this exact order, should be pretty sweet.

Comment: @кяαzєя yeah...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this:

> [image: Mio's special drink]

Yes, you can order the *exact* customized drink that Mio ordered at Starbucks, given if the additives are available. The receipt says (the price is in Yen):

```
- 1 Grande White Mocca Frappuccino   510
- Shot                                50
- Hazelnut Syrop                      50
- Caramel Sauce                        0
- Chocolate Chips                     50
- Extra Whip                    (custom)
- Total                              660
```

Source: http://blog.livedoor.jp/laisser/archives/52073325.html

Comment: Fabulous! I bet it tastes just as good as it looks!  :)